# Class group embedding in coprime extension

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $L/K$ be an extension of number fields of degree $n$. Assume that the class group of $K$ has order $h$. Prove that if $(h,n)=1$ the map $Cl(K)\rightarrow Cl(L)$, given by $I\rightarrow I\mathcal O_{L}$ is then an injection.

I tried to use the ram-rel formulas, but still I can't get to make use of the coprimality assumption, because we don't even know that $L/K$ is Galois.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let I in $O_K$, by the norme in  L / K we  obtained $N(IO_L)=I^n$

so if  class of I is trivial in cl(L), then by nome its nth power is also trivial, but  n is
coprime to the order  of class I, so itself is trivial.